# Parallel loading csv file into one table by SQLLDR with sequence (MAX,1)

Tags: multithreading, csv, sql-loader

I have around 100 threads running parallel and dumping data in a single table using sqlldr ctl file. the query generates values for ID using expression ID SEQUENCE(MAX,1).

The process fails to load files properly due to parallel execution and may be two or more threads get same ID. it works fine when I run it sequentially with one single thread.

Please suggest a workaround.

Each CSV file contains data associated with a test cases and cases are supposed to be run in parallel. I can not concatenate all files in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the data and then run a separate update in which you could update `ID` with a *traditional* oracle sequence?